# How can I parallelize a function with nested loop and conditional statement?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing

The below is used to compute the entropy of a sequence.
Is is possible to parallelize the function ?

```
def get_lempel_ziv_entropy(message: str) -> float:
         i, lib = 1, [message[0]]
        while i < len(message):
           for j in range(i, len(message)):
             message_ = message[i:j + 1]
             if message_ not in lib:
                lib.append(message_)
                break
        i = j + 1
     return len(lib) / len(message)
```

Comment: What programming language is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is practical to parallelize this function.

The outer loop cannot be parallelized since each iteration depends on the value of `lib` prepared by the previous iteration.

The inner loop *could* be parallelized, but the overheads are likely to exceed the potential speedup.  (Starting and joining a thread does not come for free, and all threads are contending for access to a mutable dictionary.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you think I can optimize the code?

Comment: What language is it?

Comment: The language is python

Comment: I don't know.  But maybe someone else might.  I have retagged the question.